# Rails query works in class but fails in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using Rails 4.0.8, I have an odd situation where a query works within an instance method, but not if the method is moved to a module included in the class.

This works:

```
class Filing < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def owner_company
    # Because of legacy database, we have to look up the company a view (Company)
    Company.where( fileno: self.owner_fileno ).first
  end
end
```

This setup does NOT work:

```
class Filing < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FilingSetup
  def company
     FilingSetup::owner_company(self)
  end
end

module FilingSetup
  def self.owner_company(filing)
    # Oddly, this query continually returns nil
    Company.where( fileno: filing.owner_fileno ).first
  end
end
```

And, if I break at the point of query in the module (using Pry), I can execute the query on the Pry console just fine and get a result.

Have I missed something obvious? Or am I up against a connection issue against a legacy database. (Company is using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter to query against a view in a SQLServer database.)

Many thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is: `FilingSetup::owner_company(self)`

You can try this:

```
class Filing < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FilingSetup
  def company
     Filing.owner_company(self)
  end
end

module FilingSetup
  def self.owner_company(filing)
    # Oddly, this query continually returns nil
    Company.where( fileno: filing.owner_fileno ).first
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Khanh, but calling FilingSetup.owner_company (instead of FilingSetup::owner_company) didn't make any difference. I did discover, though, that if I add a binding.pry statement just before the query in the module, I can get it to work, even though it doesn't trigger Pry! So, I seem to be fighting some memory quirk here I think, It certainly doesn't seem to be working as expected from such basic code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... my mistake entirely.

The query in the module was the next line after a series of "when" conditions:

```
case...
when 1, # ...
     2, # ...
     3, # ...
     owner_company = Company.where( fileno: filing.bn_owner_fileno ).first
```

and I hadn't seen the extra comma after the '3'. Good grief! All good now.